# UIButton not working after openURL in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7.1, openurl

I have multi share buttons which call openURL. After the fisrt button pressed, it opens Safari for sharing, and when I go back to my app, all buttons do not work. (only iOS 7.1, but iOS 8 works fine)

Here below is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebook_TouchUpInSide:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touch FaceBook");

    NSString *shareUrl = @"some url";

    NSString *shareText = @"some text";

    NSString *shareDescription = @"some text";

    NSString *sharePictureUrl = @"some text";

    NSString *sharingURL = [self encodeURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=388711667988471&display=page&caption=%@&description=%@&picture=%@&link=%@&redirect_uri=%@", shareText, shareDescription, sharePictureUrl, shareUrl, shareUrl]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnTwitter_TouchUpInSide:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touch Twitter");

    NSString *shareUrl = @"some url";

    NSString *shareText = @"some text";

    NSString *sharingURL = [self encodeURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post?message=%@", [self encodeURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", shareUrl, shareText]]]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Open web to share twitter!");

        sharingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=%@&text=%@&count=none/",[self encodeURL:shareUrl],[self encodeURL:shareText]];

        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnPinterest_TouchUpInSide:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touch Pinterest");

    NSString *shareUrl = @"some url";

    NSString *shareText = @"some text";

    NSString *shareMedia = @"some text";

    NSString *sharingURL = [self encodeURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pinit12://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=%@&media=%@&description=%@", shareUrl, shareMedia, shareText]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Open web to share Pinterest!");

        sharingURL = [self encodeURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=%@&media=%@&description=%@", shareUrl, shareMedia, shareText]];

        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnLinkedIn_TouchUpInSide:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touch LinkedIn");

    NSString *shareUrl = @"some url";

    NSString *shareTitle = @"some text";

    NSString *shareSummary = @"some text";

    NSString *shareSource = @"some text";

    NSString *sharingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=%@&title=%@&summary=%@&source=%@",[self encodeURL:shareUrl],[self encodeURL:shareTitle],[self encodeURL:shareSummary],[self encodeURL:shareSource]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
```

instead of this:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
    }
```

With that you move **openURL** out of *if* block **canOpenURL**